# Random text on text view

Tags: java, android-studio

How to make a random display that will display different strings of numbers for example (1-1-1, 1-2-3,1-4-5). Is it at all possible?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final java.util.Random rand = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv1.setText(rand.nextInt(6) + "-" + rand.nextInt(6) + "-" + rand.nextInt(6));

                }
            }, 2, 1000);

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: If it is working, what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Random.nextInt(10)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to get a random integer between 0 and 9, inclusive (only single-digit numbers).

```
final java.util.Random rand = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10));
```

If you want to print a new random String every 2 seconds, you can use [`java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)):

```
final java.util.Random rand = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();
new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10));
       /*
         If you are using a JLabel to display this random String, you can do:
         jLabel.setText(rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10) + "-" + rand.nextInt(10));
       */
    }
}, 0, 2000);
```

Comment: is it possible for numbers to change after a certain period of time?

Comment: @Joker99 See my revised answer.

Comment: hmm.  My app stoped after 2 second

Comment: @Joker99 What do you mean?

Comment: after period i get information that "my application keeps stopping"

Comment: everything works enough to change the size of the text view, many thanks for your help

Comment: @Joker99 No problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
      int r1 = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
      int r2 = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);        
      int r3 = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
      System.out.print(r1 + "-" + r2 + "-" + r3);
```